# Why is this function being called infinitely?

Tags: python, recursion, sqlite

I'm writing a code that's supposed to get some file names using a recursive function (*scan_folder*) and writing them into an sqlite database with a second function (*update_db*).

The first issue is, whenever *scan_folder()* calls itself, it calls *update_db()* immediately after, although it shouldn't. Because of this, the database gets updated **A LOT**. Maybe I could pop the values that get passed to the second function after it finishes, but I'd like to know why this is happening.

```
class Sub:

    def __init__(self, parent, scan_type):
        self.database = ConnectionToDatabase()
        self.database_name = ConnectionToDatabase().database_name()

    def scan_folder(self):
        connection = sqlite3.connect(self.database_name)

        try:
            cursor = connection.cursor()

            for file_name in os.listdir(self.parent):
                if file_name.endswith('.srt'):
                    if self.scan_type is True:
                        cursor.execute('SELECT count(*) FROM subs WHERE name = ?', (file_name,))

                else:
                    current_path = "".join((self.parent, "/", file_name))
                    if os.path.isdir(current_path):
                        dot = Sub(current_path, self.scan_type)

                        # I THINK HERE IS THE ERROR, ACCORDING TO PYCHARM DEBUGGER
                        # HERE THE update_db() IS CALLED AND ONLY AFTER IT FINISHES, dot.scan_folder() BEGINS
                        dot.scan_folder()

            connection.close()  # Closes connection that adds subtitle names into the database

        finally:
            self.database.update_database(dirty_files_amount)
```

Here begins the second function:

```
class ConnectionToDatabase:
    def __init__(self):
        self.database = './sub_master.db'

    def update_database(self, dirty_files_amount):
        connection_update = sqlite3.connect(self.database)
        cursor = connection_update.cursor()

            for sub_name in to_update:
                cursor.execute('UPDATE subs SET ad_found = 1 WHERE name = ?', (sub_name,))
                connection_update.commit()

        connection_update.close()
```

Comment: [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Please. That is a code dump, really unfair to expect someone to read through all that.

Comment: Scan folder does way too much. Try splitting all of the tasks into smaller ones. This way , it will be readable, and much more easy to debug. As a rule of thumb, 2 indentation is quite enough in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a hunch, but right here:

```
dot = Sub(current_path, self.scan_type)
```

You're setting it to be equals your Sub-method and in that method you have a:

```
 self.database = ConnectionToDatabase()
 self.database_name = ConnectionToDatabase().database_name()
```

That calls itself through your ConnectionToDatabase class, where your update_db is residing

Comment: I'm sorry, could you clarify? I don't understand why that would call *update_db*

Comment: Oh, sorry I meant Sub class, not method. Your dot variable is referencing to your Sub class, which in that class, you have a method "def _init_", that calls functions by itself with the "self" - keyword. In there, you're making a reference to your ConnectionToDatabase, where your "update_ database" - method is. And because of the function "dot.scan_folder()" in your "scan_folder()" - method, the method will be looping itself. That might explain why "update_database" gets called repeatedly.

Comment: I moved those references out of the class, but *update_db* is still being called after every *dot.scan_folder* call

Comment: I think I finally know what's going on, when I call *scan_folder* it enters and if/else statement which gets every file and folder in the current directory. When it doesn't find anything else there, instead of jumping back to the previous directory, it calls *update_db* before.

I think the best approach here is to just re write the code since it's a complete mess. Thanks for the help tho!

Answer (score 0):

when I call scan_folder it enters and if/else statement which gets every file and folder in the current directory. When it doesn't find anything else there, instead of jumping back to the previous directory, it calls update_db before.

The best thing to do is to just re write the whole thing, as stated previously, the functions are doing too many things.